# Video is not coming in full width

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, video

There are some video which are not coming in full width [here](http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/us_portfolio/week-1/).

I am trying to give css of iframe but not working.

I am giving height of iframe 800px then video is coming on full width but that's not the right solution, in that case I will lose responsiveness. So I want video on 100% width.

Please suggest me the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Video seems responsive to me? it is 100% on Google Chrome

Comment: video is responsive but is not on full width like black strips both sides. Height is 500 of iframe. I need it on full width. Responsivness will be handled later. thankyou